# Why is Tumbleweed a bronze badge?

Tags: discussion, badges, tumbleweed-badge

According to the Help Center (I think that's where I heard this info from), bronze badges are the easiest to get. The silver badges are a bit harder, and the gold badges are the most difficult to get.

The [Tumbleweed badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/67399#67399) is a bronze badge, which means it is supposed to be very easy to get.

However, I found that people are *always* paying attention to my questions. Every time I ask, there will be a comment/upvote/answer in less than an hour!

Stack Overflow is so full of amazing people who just like to browse all the questions and add comments and answers here and there. So it is very hard to ask a question and no one cares about it as if it were "private".

Although I just got this badge about a month ago, it is still pretty hard.

Then I asked myself, what should I ask if I want to intentionally get that badge? A good question wouldn't work, because it would get lots of upvotes. A bad question wouldn't work, because people will start shouting in the comments and downvoting. Neither would an average question work, because it would soon get answers.

Why isn't Tumbleweed a silver badge or gold badge?

EDIT:

So people said that badges' colors indicate how important the badge is. Apparently I am misled by the help center. I think we should change the text in the Help Center.

Currently, it is saying bronze badges

> are easy to get if you try!

But it's not easy to ask a question that has no views. So maybe we should change that to

> Some are easy to get if you try. Others are here to make you feel less miserable.

Comment: What would it change actually? Where are the merits?

Comment: What do you mean? @πάνταῥεῖ I just thought this would be more appropriate and make more sense.

Comment: Tumbleweed was meant to make the user feel a bit less miserable.  There is little joy in nobody looking at your question.  A gold badge could not possibly cover *that* much misery, that's suicidal.

Comment: Tumbleweed is just pure [un]luck. It's not something people are expected to *want* to achieve. It takes no skill or particular effort and is not something that demonstrates any particular familiarity with the site.

Comment: Badge color is for how *important* a badge is, not how hard or how rare it is.  Asking a question that earns a tumbleweed isn't very useful to the site.

Comment: **Tumbleweed badge** is not hard to get, i got it for asking a dumb question which got deleted by Community♦  !

Answer (score 11):

> Then I asked myself, what should I ask if I want to intentionally get that badge?

Then you're asking yourself the wrong question. Not all badges are there for you to try and attain. Do you really want the whole world to know that a question of yours went completely unnoticed? Do you really think of that as something to brag about?

Tumbleweed is there as a consolation prize. For those *unlucky enough* that their question went completely unnoticed, especially on a site with as much traffic and activity as Stack Overflow. If nothing else it serves as motivation for the user to maybe try and get more attention for their question through some other means, such as editing, or starting a bounty.

Comment: You can get it on other SE sites (all of which have less traffic/activity), too. It might actually be easier to get on SO because it's very easy for questions to fall through the cracks.